# Remote mouse pointer not rendering using RDP to connect iPad as a monitor for Ubuntu in extend mode

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, rdp, 23.10, ipad

I have a multi-monitor setup. I am using the iPad as another screen. I followed these instructions: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/06/use-ipad-as-second-monitor-ubuntu-22-04

It is usable but, the mouse pointer (using desktop mouse) does not appear in 'extend' mode. The mouse traverses multiple monitors and, in the iPad, I can see hover animations but, the cursor itself is not rendering.

On iPad, using the Microsoft Remote Desktop app. I am using Ubuntu 23.10 with Wayland (does not work in X11). The mouse pointer does not appear on the iPad. I can use the iPad mouse pointer and, it response naturally to touch events in touch mode (the caveats in the article are out-of-date) but, the remote cursor (desktop mouse pointer) does not appear. Some remote desktop software has showing or hiding the cursor as a feature.

If you know how to fix, if it is a simple setting, please let me know.